How to get a slack notifications from a custom dashboard in aws cloudwatch?
I have a custom dashboard to track metrics like count of 2xx, 3xx, 4xx, 5xx status codes. What I want is to send a slack notification when the count of 5xx > N for a period of M mins.
How do I achieve this?
I looked online and I understand bits and pieces of the steps but not the complete flow. I see the approach where we don't use lambda, and where we do. I am not able to put the information together in one flow.

You need a CloudWatch Alarm configured for your metrics with alarm and ok actions, and then use either Lambda Functions or AWS Chatbot to forward the alarm events to your slack channel.
AWS has a documentation how to configure Alarm actions with Lambda Functions .
See how to set up AWS Chatbot with Slack and the documentation on CloudWatch alarms . For this case you need to

Create an SNS topic for the alarm events.
Configure the Alarm actions to send notifications to the SNS topic.
Subscribe the Chatbot to the SNS topic.

Site note: Ad point 3, you can also subscribe a custom lambda function to that topic and achieve the same.
